# boundedness of ball-like convex subsets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a subset with the following three properties:

(i) $K$ is convex

(ii) $K$ is symmetric about $0$, that is if $k \in K$, then $-k \in K$ as well.

(iii) If $l$ is any line passing through $0$, then $l \cap B$ will be a bounded interval containing zero.

Then one can claim that $K$ is actually bounded: $K$ is contained in some ball $B_M(0)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:|x|\le M\}$.

This is a result mentioned in our functional analysis class today, our professor indicated that it is easy to show $K$ contain a small ball $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ centered around zero, then he hinted that to see the boundedness of $K$ we may do thing like follows (to my understanding:

suppose $K$ is not bounded, then we may take $x_n \in K$ with $|x_n| \to \infty$, the line containing $x_n$ would intersect at the boundary of $B_{\epsilon}(0)$, by compactness of the boundary of $B_{\epsilon}(0)$, the point of intersection would accumulate at some point $x$, then we want to show that the line through origin and $x$ would be entirely contained in $K$, contradicting properties (iii).

I find it very difficult to believe that the limiting direction would be contained in $K$, so I just want to ask here for some thoughts about it.

Thank you.